# VBS echo specific data from txt file

Tags: vbscript

Hello All i normally dig through google or try what i can think of myself for vbs automation but i hit a wall on this pulling data from txt file.

so what i need to do is to have vbs pull specific data from a txt file and echo it

.eg Wscript.echo ""&Total Dials&""

FYI its the number for total dials i'm trying to echo 
.the following  is an example of the data in the txt file

```
 Agent Time Log:
 ---------------
      Agent-Hours Logged                   311.46
      Agent-Hours Talking                  159.67
      % Talking/Logged                      51.27
      Average minutes talking per call       0.76
      Agent-Hours Wrap-Up                    6.70
      % Wrap-Up/Logged                       2.15
      Agent-Hours Viewing                    0.00
      % Viewing/Logged                       0.00
      Total Conferencing Time                0.00
      Total Pre-Conference Time              0.00
      Total Transfer Call Time               0.00
 Dialing Results:
 ----------------
      Outbound Campaign                    
        Total Dials                             209
        Total Answers                           0
        Analysis Overrides                      0
        % Analysis Overrides/Answers         0.00
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What did you tried as code ? please edit your post and show us where are you stuck ?

Comment: well when i said stuck i meant like i have no idea what to do to pull the data , i know how to open the file for reading and echo line by line but i only want the Total Dials Number i know how do this in excel but not with txt files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the idea exposed by Ekkehard.Horner, but without the *lot of RegExp(s)*

```
Option Explicit

Dim dic, fso
    Set dic = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set fso = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim colMatches, oMatch
    With New RegExp
        .Global = True
        .Multiline = True
        .Pattern = "^\s*(\S.*?)(?:\s{2,}|[ ]*\t\s*)([0-9\.]+)\s*$"
        Set colMatches = .Execute( fso.OpenTextFile("data.txt").ReadAll )
    End With

    For Each oMatch In colMatches
        dic.Add oMatch.SubMatches(0), oMatch.SubMatches(1)
    Next 

    WScript.Echo dic.Item("Total Dials")
    WScript.Echo dic.Item("% Wrap-Up/Logged")
```

The code just reads the full file, search for lines that start with zero or more blanks, followed by some text, a sequence of at least two spaces, a numeric sequence, zero or more spaces and the end of the line.

Each line found is a Match object. Each Match object contains a Submatches collection for each of the capture groups (the parts of the regular expression enclosed in parenthesis). This information is used to populate a dictionary, using the text as a key and the numeric sequence as value.

Comment: What if there's only one tab between name and value? Couldn't you use `\s+?([0-9\.]+)` instead? I guess the downfall would be if the name ends in a number (though none of these do).

Comment: @Bond, `"^\s*(\S.*?)\s+([0-9\.]+)\s*$"`. Numbers in names are not a problem, as the capture group for the numbers must be at the end of the line (with or without spaces at the end)

Comment: But couldn't it match something like `Outbound Campaign 2` (EOL)?

Comment: @Bond, answer updated to use `"^\s*(\S.*?)(?:\s{2,}|[ ]*\t\s*)([0-9\.]+)\s*$"`. Yes, you can find literals that will make it fail, but the usual way is to first determine all the posible inputs and then the regexp to match them.

Comment: Wow you literally wrote that out for me , linked it to the file and it responded the total dials Thanks you so much . i can use this to integrate into my other report scripts , admittedly i have no idea on this code  i'm guessing its under ("Scripting.Dictionary") ? Thanks again

Comment: @ MC ND  sorry to bug you again but say i need to find the number 484 in this line        1: *  T1_PA6 WI   CS         0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0   0 484   0   0

Answer (score 2):

Use a (lot of) RegExp(s) to cut the values and a Dictionary or Class to store them for further processing:

```
>> s = Join(Array("Outbound Campaign", " Total Dials    209", "Total Answers"), vbCrLf)
>> Set r = New RegExp
>> r.Pattern = "Total\sDials\s+(\d+)"
>> WScript.Echo CLng(r.Execute(s)(0).SubMatches(0))
>>
209
```

Comment: I like it, but *a lot* is not needed.